# Mutation not killed when it should be with a method with an auto-injected field

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mutation-testing, pitest

I have the following:

```
public class UnsetProperty extends Command {

    @Resource
    private SetProperty setProperty;

    public String parse(String[] args) {
        if (args.length != 4) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Incorrect number of arguments. Expected 4. Got " + args.length);
        }
        String publisher = args[0];
        String version = args[1];
        String mode = args[2];
        String property = args[3];

        /*
         * Unsetting a property is done by changing the current property to null.
         * Technically, the old property doesn't get changed, a new one is inserted with
         * a higher revision number, and it becomes the canonical one.
        */
        setProperty.setProperty(publisher, version, mode, property, null, false);
        return "";
    }
}
```

and the following test:

```
public class UnsetPropertyTest extends CommandTest {
    @Configuration
    public static class Config {

        @Bean(name = "mockSetProperty")
        public SetProperty getSetProperty() {
            return mock(SetProperty.class);
        }

        @Bean
        public UnsetProperty getUnsetProperty() {
            return new UnsetProperty();
        }

    }

    @Resource
    @InjectMocks
    private UnsetProperty unsetProperty;

    @Resource(name = "mockSetProperty")
    private SetProperty setProperty;

    // ... SNIP ...

    @Test
    public void testCallsSetPropertyWithCorrectParameters() throws SQLException, TaboolaException {
        final String[] args = new String[]{"publisher", "version", "mode", "property"};
        final String output = unsetProperty.parse(args);
        verify(setProperty).setProperty("publisher", "version", "mode", "property", null, false);
        // The above line should have killed the mutation!
        verifyNoMoreInteractions(setProperty);
        assertThat(output).isEqualTo("");
    }
}
```

The test passes, as expected. When I run it through PIT I get the following result

```
33   1. removed call to my/package/SetProperty::setProperty → SURVIVED
```

Line #33 is highlighted in the class code.

The tests examined are as follows:

- `my.package.UnsetPropertyTest.testCallsSetPropertyWithCorrectParameters(my.package.UnsetPropertyTest)`
  (32 ms)
- `my.package.UnsetPropertyTest.testUnsetThrowsForIncorrectNumberOfParameters(my.package.UnsetPropertyTest)`
  (3 ms)

Now:

- When I change the test invoke parameters (`args`) the test fails. As expected
- When I change the assertion (`verify(setProperty).setProperty(...)`) arguments the test fails. As expected.
- When I manually comment out the function call highlighted in the first code block, the test fails.

Why does the mutation survive?

I'm using Java 8, Mockito 1.9.5 and PIT 1.1.4.

Comment: Is UnsetPropertyTest listed in the "Test Examined" section of the html report?

Comment: @henry Yes. I've updated my question with the tests listed.

Comment: Are other mutants in the class killed as expected?

Comment: @henry yes, there are two other mutations in the method that are killed correctly.

Comment: Are you able to distil this down to a minimal project that reproduces the issue?

Comment: @henry This is about as basic as it gets. What are you missing?

Comment: Just need something runnable with dependencies, build file etc + to know the thing I'm looking at definitely reproduces it on your machine.

Comment: I'm new to spring-boot, so bare with me; I don't see why your test would fail.   It looks good to me.  What do you mean when you say "killed the mutation"?

Comment: What if you manually remove call to `setProperty.setProperty(publisher, version, mode, property, null, false);` and try to rut the tests? Does it fail as you expect or does it pass?

Answer (score 1):

Years later but no one seemed to mention that (Spring) `@Resource` and (Mockito) `@InjectMocks` are mutually exclusive solutions. You have multiple generated subclasses of `UnsetProperty` in play so PIT is simply confused about what's going on.

Comment: I am no longer in a position to test your answer (4.5 years *is* a long time), but hopefully someone else facing the same problem will.